# Help with axiom in propositional logic

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have an example in a propositional logic course I'm taking and I can't figure out how a certain axiom is/why it is applied in a certain step.

This link: http://www.logicinaction.org/docs/ch2.pdf

provides the chapter I'm reading.

It is example 2.24 on page 23.

I don't get how axiom(1) applies on step 4. I thought that those axioms only expand the formula en do not reduce it.

If someone could take me through all the steps that would be great. Otherwise only step 4 would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If someone wants me to place the question or text here I'll do that. Just thought that the link would save some time :).

Comment: Do you mean step 4? Step 3 doesn't use the first axiom.

Comment: Yes step 4. But I think I figured it out already. 

If I'm correct I can also replace the entire formula from step 3 by axiom(1)?
Then the formula variables would be the three atomic propositions.

Is this correct?

Comment: Step 4 is just axiom 1 with $\varphi =p$ and $\psi=q$. I don't understand what you're saying in `"I can also replace the entire formula from step 3 by axiom(1)?"`

Comment: Maybe neither do I.

Could you explain how they got from the formula in step 3 to the formula in step 4?

And if they applied axiom(1) to get from the formula in step 3 how did they do that?

Comment: Forget the previous steps. Step 4 could have been derived at step 1, it's not related to the other steps. You have an axiom that says that $\varphi \to(\psi \to \varphi)$ holds for any formulae $\varphi, \psi$. So let $\varphi =p$ and $\psi=q$ to get $p\to (q\to p)$.

Comment: Aaaah yes that is what I meant in the previous comment. They just used all the atomic propositions and placed them in the formula variables in axiom(1).

(Did I phrase that correctly?)

Which got me confused as there seemed to be no relation to step 3 at all (other than having the same atomic propositions).

Comment: It is a correct formulation. If no one gives a (correct) answer soon, I suggest you answer the question yourself.

Comment: One last question to get this correct in my mind. One can place the atomic propositions in axiom(1) because they are correct formulas as well?

Comment: "Correct formulas" is not the technical term commonly used. It should be "well formed formulas (wffs)", "close formulas" or *sometimes* simply "formulas". But yes, that is the idea. For example, since $\color{blue}{p\land (}$ isn't a well formed formula, you can't infer $\color{blue}{p\land (}\to (\psi \to \color{blue}{p\land (})$ from axiom 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple device here consists of juxtaposing the axiom and its substitution instance.  For example juxtaposing axiom 1 and step 1 like this:

```
axiom 1 (φ→(ψ→φ))


step  1 (p→((q→p)→p))
```

Now line up the parentheses arrows or equivalently connective symbols, and letters as much as possible.

```
axiom 1 ( φ → ( ψ→φ))
        | | | |
        | | | |
step  1 ( p → ( (q→p)→p))
```

But wait, make all the arrows line *only* with arrows, and allow variables to line up with any well-formed formula.  Thus, here we have

```
axiom 1 ( φ → ( ψ     → φ ) )
        | | | | |     | | | |
        | | | | ----- | | | |
step  1 ( p → ( (q→p) → p ) )
```

Thus, to get step 1 from axiom 1 we substitute φ with p (abbreviate φ/p hereafter), and ψ/(q→p).  I'll omit drawing lines from parentheses to parentheses.

```
axiom 2 (( φ → (  ψ    → χ )) → (( φ → ψ     )   → ( φ → χ)))
           | |    |      |         |   |         |   |   |
           | |    ----   |         |   -----     |   |   |
step 2  (( p → ( (q→p) → p )) → (( p → (q→p) )   → ( p → p)))
```

So,  φ/p, ψ/(q→p), χ/p gives us step 2 from axiom 2.

Now let's juxtapose step 2 and step 1, but do things a little bit differently.  Instead of matching the entirety of step 2 to step 1, let's just match the left hand side of step 2 to step 1.  Why do this?

```
step 2 (( p → ( (q → p) → p )) → (( p → (q→p)) → ( p → p)))
          | |    | | |  | | 
          | |    | | |  | |
step 1  ( p → ( (q → p) → p ))
```

Thus, since the rule of detachment says

$\alpha$

($\alpha$→$\beta$)

---

$\beta$

we can infer step 3 (( p → (q→p)) → ( p → p)).  So, we matched just the left hand side of step 2 here to the entire formula of step 1, because once we did that, we knew we could detach something.   Here's axiom 1 and step 4 juxtaposed

```
axiom 1 ( φ → ( ψ → φ ))
          | |   | | |
          | |   | | |
step 4  ( p → ( q → p ))
```

So in axiom 1 we φ/p, ψ/q.

Now let's put step 4 and step 3 next to each other similar to how we put steps 1 and 2 next to each other.

```
 step 3 ( ( p → ( q → p )) → ( p → p))
            | |   | | |
            | |   | | |
 step 4   ( p → ( q → p ))
```

And thus by detachment we may infer (p→p).

You might find the following interesting also.  Let's treat the axioms above as steps.  Thus, we'll want to match the left hand side of one axiom with the entirety of another axiom.

```
axiom 2 (( φ → ( ψ → χ )) → (( φ → ψ ) → ( φ → χ)))
           | |   | | |
           | |   | | | 
axiom 1  ( φ → ( ψ → φ ))
```

Thus in axiom 2 χ/φ makes the left hand side of axiom 2 into axiom 1 (or the left hand side of axiom 2 becomes equiform with axiom 1).  Substitutions have to come as uniform, so in axiom 2 we have to substitute *all* instance of χ with φ.  Thus, by detachment we may infer what the right side becomes after substitution

3 ((φ→ψ)→(φ→φ))).

Now let's juxtapose 3 and axiom 1

```
 3        ( ( φ →   ψ   )  →(φ→φ)))
              | |   |
              | | -----  
 axiom 1    ( φ → (ψ→φ) )
```

So, with the substitution ψ/(ψ→φ) the left hand side of 3 matches the entirety of axiom 1.  Thus, we may infer

4 (φ→φ).

I didn't make these [diagrams](http://www.clas.ufl.edu/users/jzeman/modallogic/chapter01.htm) up.  Perhaps they are due to [A. N. Prior](http://www.clas.ufl.edu/users/jzeman/modallogic/preface.htm).